# I have a problem in unity ,google services or admob

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrsMB.png)Assembly 'Assets/ExternalDependencyManager/Editor/1.2.172/Google.IOSResolver.dll' will not be loaded due to errors:
Unable to resolve reference 'UnityEditor.iOS.Extensions.Xcode'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?
Reference validation can be disabled in the Plugin Inspector.

ı have a this problem in unity.please help me.Thanks for everything.

Comment: you can ignore it, if you are making the game for Android. The project will still build.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the game Google play I am assuming you are making it for Android. You can just ignore that error because it only applies to iOS

Comment: I adding new picture now,I have yhis problem now